# Pandas use variable for Dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate Zscore for a bunch of columns but they need to be grouped by color.
I am trying to run the following code but i keep getting an error saying *'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'col*'

```
cols = list(result.columns)
for col in cols:
   col_zscore = col+'_zscore'
   result[col_zscore] = result.groupby(['color']).col.transform(lambda x : zscore(x,ddof=1))'
```

How can I pass in the column name as a variable?

Thanks

Comment: What is `cols`?

Comment: Sorry that was unclear, cols is a list of column names from the dataframe.